# Flask; Is it possible to pass a variable to my HTML template after i have rendered the template

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm not great at coding but here we go!

```
for i in range(3):
    oneval = False
    flash('hi')
    if request.method=='POST':
        flash('ho')
        while oneval != True:
            if request.form.get('check1') == 'y':
                oneval = True
                ques = questions(question=twoQs[i][0],answer=twoQs[i][1])
                db.session.add(ques)
                db.session.commit()
            elif request.form.get('check2') == 'n':
                oneval = True
                ques = questions(question=twoQs[i][0],answer=twoQs[i][2])
                db.session.add(ques)
                db.session.commit()
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('user'))

return render_template('form.html', list=twoQs, i=i)
```

Here is a piece of code that takes a list of questions and sees what the user chooses (yes or no answers using checkboxes in my html code below) I'm using i as an iterator for my questions in the html. However when I pass i into my template it remains 0 the whole time and does not go to 1 or 2. Is there a way to update / refresh the value of i inside the template? without rendering it again?

```
<html>
    <p>{{list[i][0]}}</p>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="y" >
        {{list[i][1]}}
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="n" >
        {{list[i][2]}}
        <p><input type = 'submit' value="submit"/></p>
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine if you created a string in python by collecting a number from a user and then inserting it into the string.

```py
def my_function():
    user_input = 1
    return 'You entered: {}'
```

After you generate that string, how would you change it? The answer is that you would have to re-render the string. So if the user changed their input to `2` then you need to re-run the function.

The same thing is true with Flask and the `render_html` method.

Once you render the HTML and return it to the users browser, there is no way for flask to reach into the browser and change the value any more than you could change the contents of a letter that has already been mailed.

The solution is to send a new HTML file to the user when their inputs change.

One way to do this is to allow the user to change their input in the browser, send a new request to your flask server, and then re-render the html and deliver it again to the user's browser. This requires a full page re-load.

Another option is to use Javascript in the browser to send a request to flask to update the user's input and then use the response to update just that one part of the HTML. This is how most modern web applications are built.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. I will have to find a way to run my code so that it re renders if an update is required as I sadly don't have the time to learn javascript as of now!!